# /opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: devops, chef-infra, chef-client, chef-workstation

When I am bootstrapping a node, I'm getting this error:

```
error :The following error occurred on 172.31.2.207:
error :/opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone solve this problem?

I tried the below command:

```
knife bootstrap 172.31.2.207 --ssh-user ec2-user --sudo -i node-key.pem -N node1
```

Answer (score 4):

This command is working properly:-

```
yum install libxcrypt-compat
```